# How to load jQuery with Assetic from layout template before JavaScript tags in child template?

Tags: jquery, symfony, twig, assetic

As we can read in [Symfony2 documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/templating.html#including-stylesheets-and-javascripts-in-twig), JavaScript files have to be declared at the bottom of body tag.

However, if I declare jQuery library in layout template and if I want to use jQuery in child template I have this error :

> $ is not defined

It seems jQuery is loaded after my script tag. When I put an alert message at the top of jQuery file, alert is displayed.

Any idea to load jQuery before ?

Find below my base, layout and child templates.

app/Resources/views/layout.html.twig:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        {% block stylesheets %}
                {# ... #}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>

    <body>            
        <div id="container">
            {# ... #}
        </div>

        {% block javascripts %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

src/MyBundle/resources/views/layout.html.twig:

```
{% extends "::layout.html.twig" %}

{% block main %}
    {% block mybundle_body %}
    {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %} 
    {% javascripts
        '@MyBlogBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js' %}
        <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock javascripts %}
```

src/MyBundle/resources/views/MyBundle/modify.html.twig:

```
{% extends "MyBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% block mybundle_body %}

    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Enable the file uploader
    $(function() { // my error here : $ is not defined
        new PunkAveFileUploader({ 
            {# ... #}
        });
    });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a new inheritance.
So your script will always be after your jQuery.

```
{% block javascripts %} 
    {% javascripts
        '@MyBlogBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js' %}
        <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
    {% block script %}
    {% endblock script %}
{% endblock javascripts %}
```

src/MyBundle/resources/views/MyBundle/modify.html.twig:

```
{% extends "MyBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% block mybundle_body %}
   //some stuff
{% endblock %}

{% block script %}

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Enable the file uploader
    $(function() { // my error here : $ is not defined
        new PunkAveFileUploader({ 
            {# ... #}
        });
    });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, like you said, jQuery is loaded **after** your `<script>` tag, so when your script tries to use jQuery (with the `$` sign), jQuery is not yet defined.

I'd move the `{% block javascripts %}` to the head tag.

Comment: Thanks. However, I'm wondering why the `{% block javascripts %}` is at the bottom of body tag in [Symfony2 documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/templating.html#including-stylesheets-and-javascripts-in-twig).

Comment: If the script is only needed when the page is fully loaded, you can place it at the bottom of the body tag, that way the page will load the visual (html) content first and will be displayed to the user a little faster. But if you need it before the page is fully loaded you need to place it earlier in the code.